# How much military equipment has Ukraine received externally since the situation escalated in February?

Tags: armed-conflict, military, ukraine

I noticed that before the war broke out in Feb 24, there was military equipment sent to Ukraine from NATO countries, for example [U.S. sent 80 tons of military equipment (part of an additional $200M "lethal aid") in Jan 25](https://thehill.com/policy/defense/591358-us-shipment-of-military-equipment-munitions-arrives-in-ukraine) (Some say 90 tons. *cf. the weight of an M1 main battle tank is ~60 tons*). Germany [offered 5,000 helms to Ukraine in Jan 27](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/27/germanys-offer-to-send-5000-helmets-to-ukraine-provokes-outrage.html). Please comment below for more military supplies to Ukraine in January or early February that I didn't mention.

After the War broke out, I noticed that Australia is preparing for [new military equipment to Ukraine.](https://english.kyodonews.net/news/2022/02/311360437c6b-australia-sending-military-equipment-medical-supplies-to-ukraine.html). But can anyone summarize (all, if possible) the military equipment Ukraine obtained externally since the situation escalates in February? (The only information I could get is from mainstream media.)

---

Update: [Poland's aid has arrived Ukraine on Feb 25.](https://www.cnn.com/europe/live-news/ukraine-russia-news-02-25-22/h_b821ab5fc5308a00b02b90571718c54b)

[Slovakia is giving to Ukraine](https://twitter.com/Ondrejcsak/status/1497524166160965636?s=20&t=FYl8OS1VrDErgLhLpu1ccg)

Comment: Maybe of use: "What military assistance has the UK and its Western allies given to Ukraine?" https://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/SN07135/SN07135.pdf - "The UK already has more than 900 British military personnel based in Estonia, more than 100 in Ukraine as part of Operation Orbital, and a Light Cavalry Squadron of around 150 people, is deployed to Poland. Op Orbital has trained 22k Ukrainian troops since 2015, and further military trainers were sent to the country earlier this month to support the training of Ukrainian forces to use 2000 missiles sent from the UK" Jan2022

Comment: Not sure what the tank weight is doing here.  The intent was never to provide Ukraine with tanks or airplanes, those would be useful in attack as well as defense.  And Ukraine has tons of (older) tanks already, what it is lacking is a way to keep those tanks from getting destroyed by Russian planes.  Past details on shipments to Ukraine have been:  rifles, anti-tank missiles, communication gear.  Lighter weight stuff, probably useful too in later phases, if a guerrilla resistance develops.  I didn't DV btw and it is a fair question and at least part of it is on the record.

Comment: 5000 helmets from Germany. How pathetic. Germans should have learned by now that the lesson from WW2 is not that looking away solves problems.

Comment: @Trilarion Germany is avoiding providing lethal aid to Ukraine.  Part of it is commercial self-interest, part guilty feelings about WW2 and its massacres of Russians.  But seems their position towards Russia is hardening.  Lots of people are going to revisit the "USA just as bad as Russia", methink.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Germany could have easily provided much more non-lethal aid, like body armor, radio equipment, night vision googles, ... and for the guilty feelings about WW2: shouldn't that result in an increased desire to help democracies that are attacked by autocratic regimes wherever? But basically I just wanted to comment on the comparatively little value of the German material support, at best it was symbolic. And in such a situation purely symbolic support may even backfire and come across as hypocrisy. Although cancellation of NordStream2 is something more substantial.

Comment: For the question: It might be difficult to answer, because the exact amount of military support is probably sensitive information and will not just like this be made public. We would probably like to know that, but we will likely not get to know that. Doesn't mean that it's a bad question, just an impossible to answer one.

Comment: @Trilarion disagree.  A number of countries have gone on the record saying what they are sending to Ukraine.  While we don't necessarily know everything that is being sent, claiming that we know nothing is incorrect.  For one thing, those are expensive weapons, their funding and acquisition is part of the public record and 500 "missing" Stingers - to take Germany's better-late-than-never example - would be extremely worrying if they were found to have disappeared from national armories without explanation.